# CSS max-height transition for dropdowns not working in mobile/hamburger view of a responsive menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, css-transitions

Apologies if you've read something like this from me recently, but I've changed the code a bunch and gone through different problems and wanted to start fresh instead of continually re-editing and replying to my original post.

I've built a responsive clickable dropdown menu from CSS and vanilla javascript. I want the dropdowns to smoothly transition in and out - but for some reason, the transition effect isn't working in the mobile view (which is the CSS I built first) - only in the expanded browser view (at a breakpoint of min-width: 768px). There have been various points in the development of this menu where the transitions worked just fine in mobile mode; it has worked and not worked on and off for reasons I haven't figured out. When broken, as it is now, its behavior is to pause for the length of the transition before appearing or disappearing.

Because transitions don't work at all with a display:none/display:block toggle, I am using max-height: 0; overflow: hidden as the default CSS to hide the dropdowns. The javascript toggles a class of max-height: 800%, as well as a separate class that restyles the button to highlight it. (I'd use max-height: 100%, but for some reason in expanded mode the dropdowns are inheriting the 60px fixed height of the navbar and/or .menu__box. I've decided not to fight that battle against whatever is going on there unless y'all tell me it's part of the problem.) The javascript also removes these classes when you click outside the button area. I don't think the javascript itself is the problem as it does seem to do its job of toggling the classes I need, but I'm including it here for completeness' sake.

The main piece of CSS for the transition is here, in the code that also hides the dropdowns:

```
.shows__dropdownhider, .more__dropdownhider {max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; min-width: 165px;
   -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
   -moz-transition-duration: .25s;
   -o-transition-duration: .25s;
   transition-duration: .25s;}
```

I also tried specifically targeting the max-height property, but it didn't make any difference:

```
.shows__dropdownhider, .more__dropdownhider {max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; min-width: 165px;
   -webkit-transition: max-height .25s ease;
   -moz-transition: max-height .25s ease;
   -o-transition: max-height .25s ease;
   transition: max-height 0.25s ease;}
```

Please note that I am deliberately not using Bootstrap or anything else that comes with lots of inbuilt CSS because I have to integrate this menu into a 25-year-old website with hundreds and hundreds of archival pages going back to when it was a frames-based site and every page was built with tables! Ah, 1998... (There is, in fact, a Bootstrap-based menu currently on the site and it makes lots of very old pages go boom. Which is why I'm trying to write something standalone to replace it.)

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://www.sacredfools.org/newmenu3.html). Yes, I know stuff is not in the proper semantic parts of the page; the CSS will eventually be hived off to a proper .css file when I've got it finished.

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/cklemow/pen/JjmBrjq)

Thanks for any help!

Menu HTML (the  caret stuff is a Fontawesome down-caret icon):

```
<nav>

  <div class="logo">

<a class="ourname" href="#">
<img src="http://www.sacredfools.org/images/2d-logo-white-on-black-500px-128x128.png">
SACRED FOOLS</a></div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="menutoggler" class="toggler">
    <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>

  <ul class="menu__box">

    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">TICKETS</a></li>

<div class="dropdownholder">
    <li class="shows__dropbtn"><a class="menu__item shows__dropbtn" id="shows__button" onclick="shows__dropdown()">SHOWS
             <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>

        <li class="shows__dropdownhider" id="shows__dropdowncontainer">
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">All Shows</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Calendar</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem menu__lastdropdown" href="#">Past Productions</a>
        </li>
</div>

<div class="dropdownholder">
    <li class="more__dropbtn"><a class="menu__item more__dropbtn" id="more__button" onclick="more__dropdown()">MORE
             <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>

        <li class="more__dropdownhider" id="more__dropdowncontainer">
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Directions</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Members & Staff</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Get Involved</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">About</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Mission</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Anti-Racism</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">EDI</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Education & Outreach</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Press</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Awards</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Contact Us</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem" href="#">Mailing List</a>
           <a class="menu__dropdownitem menu__lastdropdown" href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
</div>

    <li><a class="menu__item menu__highlight menu__lastitem" href="#">DONATE</a></li>

        <li><a class="menu__item menu__social" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="menu__item menu__social" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="menu__item menu__social" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-instagram"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
  
</nav>

<div class="menuspacer"></div>
```

Javascript for the dropdown toggle buttons:

```
/* SHOWS Dropdown */

function shows__dropdown() {
  document.getElementById("shows__dropdowncontainer").classList.toggle("menu__dropdownshow");
  document.getElementById("shows__button").classList.toggle("menu__toggledon");
}


/* MORE Dropdown */

function more__dropdown() {
  document.getElementById("more__dropdowncontainer").classList.toggle("menu__dropdownshow");
  document.getElementById("more__button").classList.toggle("menu__toggledon");
}

/* Close dropdowns when clicking outside */

window.onclick = function(e) {

  if (!e.target.matches('.shows__dropbtn')) {
  var shows__dropdowncontainer = document.getElementById("shows__dropdowncontainer");
    if (shows__dropdowncontainer.classList.contains('menu__dropdownshow')) {
      shows__dropdowncontainer.classList.remove('menu__dropdownshow');
    }
  }

  if (!e.target.matches('.shows__dropbtn')) {
  var shows__button = document.getElementById("shows__button");
    if (shows__button.classList.contains('menu__toggledon')) {
      shows__button.classList.remove('menu__toggledon');
    }
  }

  if (!e.target.matches('.more__dropbtn')) {
  var more__dropdowncontainer = document.getElementById("more__dropdowncontainer");
    if (more__dropdowncontainer.classList.contains('menu__dropdownshow')) {
      more__dropdowncontainer.classList.remove('menu__dropdownshow');
    }
  }


  if (!e.target.matches('.more__dropbtn')) {
  var more__button = document.getElementById("more__button");
    if (more__button.classList.contains('menu__toggledon')) {
      more__button.classList.remove('menu__toggledon');
    }
  }

}

</script>
```

CSS (the .toggler/.hamburger code for the hamburger button was copied from elsewhere and I don't really understand how it works; the rest is my own code):

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

nav {background-color: #282828;
     padding: 0; margin: 0;
     position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
     width: 100%; z-index: 2;
}

nav, .menuspacer {height: 60px}

.logo {color: #ffffff; font-size: 12pt; float: left;
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-weight: bold; z-index: 3;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   }

.logo img {height: 60px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;
 vertical-align:middle;}

a.ourname:link, a.ourname:visited, a.ourname:hover, a.ourname:active
 {text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;}

.toggler{
    z-index:2;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hamburger > div{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    height: 2px;
    width: 60%;
    transition: all  0.4s ease;
}

.hamburger > div::before,
.hamburger > div::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    transition: all  0.4s ease;
}

.hamburger > div::after{
    top: 8px;
}

.toggler:checked + .hamburger > div{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.toggler:checked + .hamburger > div::before{
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: white;
}

.toggler:checked + .hamburger > div::after{
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    background: white;
}

.toggler:checked ~ .menu__box{
    left: 0px;
}

.menu__box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: -100%;
  width: 280px;
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 60px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
  height: -o-calc(100% - 60px);
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #282828;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block; float: none;
  padding: 11px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  border-top: 1px dotted #ffffff;
}

.dropdownholder {position: relative}

.menu__dropdownitem {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.shows__dropdownhider, .more__dropdownhider {max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; min-width: 165px;
   -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
   -moz-transition-duration: .25s;
   -o-transition-duration: .25s;
   transition-duration: .25s;}

.menu__dropdownshow {max-height: 800%}

.shows__dropbtn, .more__dropbtn {cursor: pointer;}

.menu__lastdropdown {padding-bottom: 11px}

.menu__lastitem {border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffffff;}

.menu__item:hover, .menu__item:active,
.menu__dropdownitem:hover, .menu__dropdownitem:active {color: #FB0901}

.menu__item:hover, .menu__item:active,
.menu__dropdownitem:hover, .menu__dropdownitem:active {background-color: #000000}

.menu__highlight {background-color: #404040}

.menu__social {float: left; border: none; font-size: 20pt}

.menu__social:hover, .menu__social:active {background-color: transparent}

.fa-caret-down {margin: 5px; font-size: 8pt; float: right}

.menu__toggledon {color: #FB0901; background-color: #000000;}


@media (min-width: 768px) {

.toggler, .hamburger {display: none}

.toggler:checked ~ .menu__box{
    left: auto;
}

.menu__box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: static;
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  min-height: auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0s ease;
}

.menu__item {
  padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  border-top: none;
  padding-top: 19px; padding-bottom: 19px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.menu__social {font-size: 15pt; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px;}

.final__social {padding-right: 15pt}

.menu__social:hover, .menu__social:active {text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .75);}

.menu__dropdownitem {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  padding-right: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.shows__dropdownhider, .more__dropdownhider {
  position: absolute; background-color: #282828;
 }

.menu__lastitem {border-bottom: none;}

.fa-caret-down {margin-left: 5px; font-size: 12pt; float: none;
 padding: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px}

.menu__highlight {background-color: transparent;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; font-weight: 500;
   border: 1px solid #ffffff;
   padding: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   text-shadow: none;}

.menu__highlight:hover, .menu__highlight:active {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;}

.menu__box :nth-child(4) {order: 1;}

}
```

Comment: Just accidentally discovered that if I give a fixed height (not max-height, but height) to the dropdownholder div that wraps around the button and its associated dropdowns, the transition on the dropdowns work - but of course that doesn't work for this use case in the mobile view, where I need the height to be variable.

Also, if I remove the dropdownholder wrapper entirely, the dropdown transition works in mobile view... but I need that wrapper there to keep the dropdowns in their proper place for the expanded view.

Does this give any clue as to what might be happening?

Comment: Another accidental discovery:  the mobile dropdown transition works if there's no doctype declared. Not a viable solution, but hey. Another clue. Not one I can interpret, but a clue nonetheless.